# Sonata admin bundle get class object

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using sonata admin bundle for my project, in my admin class, I'm trying to get the class object to get data like:

```
$this->getSubject()->getName();
```

However, the out come is:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in MyAdmin.php line 169
```

Anyone know what's wrong? Appreciate!

**Updated** 21/09/2014
Here is what I am tying to do:

```
public function getExportFields() {
    $this->getSubject()->getPurchasePerItem; //Here return error!
    return [
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Order Number') => 'id', 
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('First Name') => 'customer.First_name',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Last Name') => 'customer.Last_name',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Contact') => 'customer.contact',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Email') => 'customer.email',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Street') => 'customer.street',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Town') => 'customer.town',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('State') => 'customer.state',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Postcode') => 'customer.postcode',
        //items may more than one
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Item') => 'purchasePerItem[0].product.model',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Item_Qty') => 'purchasePerItem[0].quantity',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Item_price') => 'purchasePerItem[0].product.price',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Total') => 'total_amount',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Shipping') => 'delivery_fee',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Order time') => 'createdAt',
        $this->getTranslator()->trans('Last Update') => 'updatedAt',

        ];
```

Comment: You need to provide some more code regarding `getSubject()` relation

Comment: All I need to just want to use the methods regarding to the object of this admin class. Anyway, I will update my question.

Comment: It looks like subject is not set. 
It need to be set explicit - tak a look at https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Controller/CRUDController.php#L344
Where is it happening, in what action? Is it Sonata predefined action (show, edit) or some custom action?

Comment: I now see that method name is 'getExportFields', so my guess is that it is export action. So the answer is simple - there is no subject in this action. What acctualy are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, @tiriana you are right.